# How can I render jinja template f-string?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, jinja2

Here is my test code:

test_jinja.py

```
i = 10
aa = f"{{{{ execution_date.subtract(hours=8).add(hours={i}).format('YYYY-MM-DD_H') }}}}"
```

main.py

```
import jinja2
import pathlib
import pendulum

# assume it is an unittest function
context = {  # your variables to pass to template
    'logical_date': pendulum.now(),
    'execution_date': pendulum.now(),

    'params': pendulum.now(),
    'dag_run': ''

}


path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent
filename = 'test_jinja.py'

jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(path),
)
rendered = jinja_env.get_template("temp/"+filename).render(context)
print(rendered)
```

The error occurs like this: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'`
The file template does not recognize the grammar..

The results are expected : 2023-09-25_1

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish with this code? Are you trying to generate a Python source file from a template? Do you expect that source file to be run at some point? Step by step, how do you think the expected output of `2023-09-25_1` should be produced?

Comment: In my airflow code, I have an f-string type as shown in the question and I want to test it.
I want the result to be something like `2023-09-25_1`.

Comment: @이진환 please provide your Airflow code, as according to the example it is assumed that `test_jinja.py` is a template itself, so you can't use variables inside a template.